# MS (Project) Find Strings in text10 and change font color

Tags: vba, fonts, colors, ms-project

I'm changing the color of font in MS Project based on Percentage complete and Names in text10 column.  The percentages work however can someone give me a steer on the names I would be grateful, I want to highlight in teal if for example "David" or "Darren" or both are in `Text10` field.

Any help gratefully received.

```
Sub text()

Dim Ctr As Integer

ViewApply "Gantt Chart"
OutlineShowAllTasks
FilterApply "All Tasks"
SelectAll

For Ctr = 1 To ActiveSelection.Tasks.Count
    SelectRow Row:=Ctr, rowrelative:=False
    If Not ActiveSelection.Tasks(1) Is Nothing Then
        If ActiveSelection.Tasks(1).Text10 = ("David") & ("Darren") Then
            Font Color:=pjTeal
        Else
            If ActiveSelection.Tasks(1).PercentComplete = 100 Then
                Font Color:=pjGreen
            Else
                If ActiveSelection.Tasks(1).PercentComplete = 0 Then
                    Font Color:=pjBlack
                Else
                    If ActiveSelection.Tasks(1).PercentComplete > 0 < 100 Then
                        Font Color:=pjBlue
                    Else
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next Ctr

End Sub
```

Comment: @Mat'sMug gotta love the Ducky :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
If ActiveSelection.Tasks(1).Text10 = ("David") & ("Darren") Then
```

To:

```
If ActiveSelection.Tasks(1).Text10 = "David" Or ActiveSelection.Tasks(1).Text10 = "Darren" Then
```

---

**Edit 1:** Better style of coding (untested as I don't have MS-Project installed at home - can test it tomorrow morning)

```
Option Explicit

Sub text()

ViewApply "Gantt Chart"
OutlineShowAllTasks
FilterApply "All Tasks"

Dim T As Task

For Each T In ActiveProject.Tasks
    If Not T Is Nothing Then
        SelectRow T.UniqueID, RowRelative:=False '<-- there's no escape, in Ms-Project you need to select the Task's row in order to modify it's Font color
        If T.Text10 = "David" Or T.Text10 = "Darren" Then
            Font Color:=pjTeal
        Else
            Select Case T.PercentComplete
                Case 100
                    Font Color:=pjGreen
                Case 0
                    Font Color:=pjBlack
                Case Else
                    Font Color:=pjBlue
            End Select
        End If
    End If
Next T

End Sub
```

---

## Edit 2: added a new logics for added information by PO.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColorTasks()

ViewApply "Gantt Chart"
OutlineShowAllTasks
FilterApply "All Tasks"

Dim T As Task

For Each T In ActiveProject.Tasks
    If Not T Is Nothing Then
        SelectRow T.ID, RowRelative:=False

        Select Case T.Text10
            Case "David"
                 Font Color:=pjBlue
            Case "Mary"
                Font Color:=pjTeal
            Case "Bill"
                Font Color:=pjBlack
            Case "Sandra"
                Font Color:=pjPurple
        End Select

        ' I think you wanted this outside the case of the people in Text10
        If T.PercentComplete = 100 Then
            Font Color:=pjGreen
        Else
            If DateDiff("d", T.Finish, ActiveProject.CurrentDate) > 0 Then
                Font Color:=pjRed
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next T

End Sub
```

Comment: Looping through the task collection and using `SelectRow` with the task's UniqueID only works if no tasks were ever deleted (Task ID = Task Unique ID), no external tasks are present, and the tasks in the view are sorted by Task ID. The OP's version of selecting the tasks and looping through the selection works better.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, if i need to add a line to say change font to red if todays date is greater than finish date.  Would it be something like the following.?

Comment: If ActiveSelection.Tasks(1).finish < currentdate Then
                Font Color:=pjRed

Comment: For some reason the teal just would not work so i used the following.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()

Dim Ctr As Integer

ViewApply "Gantt Chart"
OutlineShowAllTasks
FilterApply "All Tasks"
SelectAll
For Ctr = 1 To ActiveSelection.Tasks.Count
    SelectRow Row:=Ctr, rowrelative:=False
    If Not ActiveSelection.Tasks(1) Is Nothing Then
        If ActiveSelection.Tasks(1).Text10 = "David" Then
            Font Color:=pjBlue
        Else
        If ActiveSelection.Tasks(1).Text10 = "Mary" Then
            Font Color:=pjTeal
        Else
        If ActiveSelection.Tasks(1).Text10 = "Bill" Then
            Font Color:=pjBlack
        Else
        If ActiveSelection.Tasks(1).Text10 = "Sandra" Then
            Font Color:=pjPurple
        Else
        If ActiveSelection.Tasks(1).PercentComplete = 100 Then
            Font Color:=pjGreen
        Else    
        If ActiveSelection.Tasks(1).finish < currentdate Then 
            Font Color:=pjRed
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
    Next Ctr
End Sub
```

Comment: The code is working with exeption of being able to highlight the font as red if todays date is great than the finish date and the percentage complete is less than 100.  I would be very grateful if you could assist with that or point me somewhere where i can work it out please?

Comment: Try the code under **EDIT 2** in my answer above - I think this is what you wanted

Comment: That works like a dream, many thanks for your help i was going insane trying to get it to work.  Kind Regards VBvirg20